# Mapping @Query with multiple column selection to an Java object in a @Repository - is it possible out of the box?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

Is it possible to map the results of a Hibernate `@Query` like this  (in a `@Repository` interface extending `@JpaRepository`):

```
@Query("select u.id, u.email, u.status from user u")
public SimpleUserDTO getAllUsersSimpleData();
```

directly to a Java object like this:

```
public class SimpleUserDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String status;
}
```

What I know, is that doing something like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select u.id, u.email, u.status from user u");
```

the result can be extracted to a `List<Object[]>`:

```
List<Object[]> users = (List<Object[]>) query.list();
```

But is it possible to map it directly to a `List<SimpleUserDTO>` without writing additional method that will map the values to `SimpleUserDTO`?

Comment: Have you tried Hibernate Projections? Or the Interface-Based Projections of Spring?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options.

**Option 1: Constructor Expression:**

```
@Query("select new <insert_package_here>.SimpleUserDTO(u.id, u.email, u.status) from user u")
public List<SimpleUserDTO> getAllUsersSimpleData();
```

**Option 2: Use Interface projection**

Turn your DTO into an interface and you can use it without @Query annotation

```
public List<SimpleUserDTO> getAllUsersSimpleData();
```

Please find out more about projections and Spring Data JPA in the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: I have simplified the code, but in reality, the query looks like this: `select u.id, u.email, u.status, a.postalCode from user u join address a on (u.id = a.user_id)` - so it includes another table. Will this also work?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: Trying now the solution using projection ;)